# RegExp to match pattern with ranged mask till 596

Tags: reactjs, regex, regex-group, react-imask

I have got an input mask as an array =

`[/[0-5]/, /\d/, /\d/, ":", /[0-5]/, /\d/, ":", /[0-5]/, /\d/, ".", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/,]`

It corresponds formatting for example - `344:43:43.565`

The maximum allowed number for first fracture (where `344` is now) - is 596

I am able to set ranges for all fractures, but I cannot combine RegExp to match `596` as a maximum allowed fracture at the beginning.

So, the idea is to accept `589:43:43.565` but to cancel `597:43:43.565` input number (as `596` is max allowed for this portion of a fracture)

I've created a RegExp for whole time (as a string) -

`/^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|5[0-8][0-9]|59[0-6]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9](?:[:]\d{1,3})?)?$/`

But unable to combine single RegExp into mask

Comment: It is impossible to "combine it into mask", because mask applies each pattern to a single char at a specified position.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regexp is too strict. Probably typing in the input is impossible? You would need to make more colons and digits optional. The easier solution might be to have 4 inlined inputs and hardcode the separators (:/.) on the page, between the inputs.